# Export to Excel In PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I want to export Mysql data to excel With Date Range & DropDown Value.
I used following code but it won't work,Please Suggest me what is wrong  in my code.
Or any other way to export to excel with date range & dropdown value.
Thank You in Advance

```
    <?php

$DB_Server = "localhost";  //MySQL Server 
$DB_Username = "root";  //MySQL Username 
$DB_Password = "";  //MySQL Password 
$DB_DBName = "yuleads"; //MySQL Database Name 
$DB_TBLName = "leads"; //MySQL Table Name
$filename = "MIS_Report";  //File Name



//create MySQL connection
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName WHERE Process_Name='$ProcessName' AND DATE_FORMAT(`Entry_Date`, '%Y-%m-%d')  BETWEEN '$fdt' and  '$tdt'";

$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());

//select database

$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());

//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect)or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());

$file_ending = "xls";

//header info for browser

header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");


//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)

$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields

for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++)
{
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t"; 
} 
print("\n");

//end of printing column names
//start while loop to get data

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";

        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }

        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);

 $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);

        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";

    }

?>
```

Comment: At least use the built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function, and a tab or comma separated value files isn't an xls file; but it might help if your explain what you mean by "doesn't work"

Comment: Means it doesn't export data As date range & dropdown value

Comment: So have you tried debugging the SQL statements? You're deliberately suppressing any SQL errors, which isn't sensible... but your description of the problem is still vague - does it export all data from the table? Does it extract no data?

Comment: No it dint show any error,
But the excel sheet is blank

Comment: Well it won't show any error.... you're deliberately suppressing errors - does the SQL work!!!!

Comment: Yes it works fine when i remove the codition of date range & dropdown value

Comment: So the problem is in your SQL query, so do a bit of debugging to show what it is actually executing as the query.... echo $sql and try running it manually... and then perhaps learn to use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: I am not able to sort it out ,can you please suugest me for export to excel with date range & dropdown vlaue

Comment: You need to fix that SQL statement... stop suppressing the errors with `@`, echo your $sql so that you can test it using phpmyadmin or MySQL command line

Comment: Sorry i din't get you, I am new to php , Please help me for this

Comment: I can't run it for you, you have your database, not me... install a tool like phpmyadmin to make it easier for you to test your SQL queries

Comment: Yes , But My query is that i want to export data to excel by given date range & Dropdown value . Which is not working But, When I remove 
WHERE Process_Name='$ProcessName' AND DATE_FORMAT(`Entry_Date`, '%Y-%m-%d')  BETWEEN '$fdt' and  '$tdt'
Then it works fine

Comment: Which is why you need to actually look at the query that is being created when you do have that WHERE clause

Comment: WHERE clause  din't work